# How to loop animations

Tags: animation, timeline, looping

[image]

If the orbital period of earth is 1, the period of Mercury is 0.241.

In the Timeline, I scaled Mercury to said period by pressing S, .241.

How can I get Mercury to continue it's motion rather than waiting for the animation to restart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the object, in the *Dopesheet* select its keyframes (to only see this object's keyframes, use the *Only Include Channels Relating To Selected Objects* option, small arrow icon button) and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Linear Extrapolation*, and the object should continue its rotation infinitely.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  One thing...  Linear Extrapolation from the Dope Sheet didn't do anything.  From the Graph Editor, however- it worked perfectly.  Thanks!